# Nginx not evaluating conditionals

Tags: nginx

Take the following nginx config snippet:

```
if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, HEAD';
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
  add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
  add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
  add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
  return 204;
}
if ($request_method != OPTIONS) {
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, HEAD';
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
}
```

The headers are not applied to the response regardless of the request type.

If the `if` statements are removed entirely, leaving just the following it works fine:

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, HEAD';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
```

From what I can see there are two opposing conditionals and neither seems to be evaluated.

Comment: Same for me, it seems that add_header within if is simply not supported (1.1.19).